# Start DB2 CLPPLUS Tool from linux server

Tags: db2, clpplus

I'm trying to start CLPPLUS  from a linux server (I'm using MobaXterm to connect remotly to the Linux server) but it does not work (either the CLPPLUS tool is started nor an error is thrown).

I can start DB2 CLP on Server using the following line of code :

`db2 connect to sample`

Is it possible to start CLPPLUS on the server the same way we start DB2 CLP?

I have tried the following lines  of code but it does nothing ( either the CLPPLUS tool is started nor an error is thrown).

1. `clpplus`

2)`clpplus userid@host:portnumber/database`

Is it possible to start CLPPLUS from the server as we can do with DB2 CLP?

Comment: clpplus is based on Java. Is it installed correctly?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the distro name and version, and add the plain text output of the command db2level, and the value of the environment variables TERM and LANG

Comment: Thank you data-henrik ! The clpplus tool was not installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When asking for help with Db2, always mention the platform and version. For Db2-luw,  use the db2level command to report fixpack and version information.

For clpplus, it will by default open a new window,  which is not what you want if you have only an ssh terminal into the hostname running the Db2-server.

So in this case,  use the clpplus command with the option -nw which tells clpplus to use the current session instead of starting a new window.

You can get more details with the -verbose option.

Please use the documentation for your Db2- server aqua version for example
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=clpplus-command

Comment: Thank you Mao.  Next time I'll mentione the plateforme and the version.   The problem is solved.  Clpplus was not installed correctly. The antlr-jar were missing.